# Express API accessible on localhost but not on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, angular, google-app-engine, express, mean-stack

I have two MEAN (angular 4) apps and I want one to get data from the other's api. The strange thing is that with one app the base url is the same for the site and the api. This one returns the data. The other app has a different base url and the app does not return the data.

APP1 (data successfully returned)

```
base url: https://de***ta.appspot.com
api url: https://de***ta.appspot.com/api/droplet/:id
```

So when I serve this app the droplet I am looking for gets returned in json format as you would expect using this code:

```
app.get('/api/droplets/:id', function(req, res) {
  Droplets.findOne({
    _id: req.params.id
      }, function(err, droplet) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(droplet);
      });
  });
```

APP2 (returns index.html)

```
base url: https://differenturl.appspot.com
api url: https://de***ta.appspot.com/api/droplet/:id
```

So here the base urls are different and the api url, when called from the http service in angular, returns index.html. I assume it is due to this code in the server:

```
app.use('*', function(req, res) {
  return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist', 'index.html'));
});
```

But what I do not understand is why one api call returns the index, while the other one activated the route as specified.

I would need to know why this happens and how to access the api from an external base url.

**Update**

If I run the api server locally on localhost, it returns the data I want when I simply type the url (http://localhost:8080/api/droplet/fhkssdkajfhds). But when I type it with the google cloud hosted site we don't get it. Perhaps it's an issue with how the google cloud serves express apps?

Answer (score 0):

... I think it's  a `CORS problem` ..could it be? .can you try just for test to open the api to ALL ?

so for example install this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors
and then

```
var cors = require('cors')

var app = express()
app.use(cors())
```

Comment: No that's not it. I have this code and it sends the preflight request and then sends the correct proper request. It returns the 200 status code, it just returns the html page rather than the json I want.